# Empire of Code (python)

Tags: python

Good day! I decided to learn Python by playing the EOC. So I have a task to write a function that has to count the area of the circle, the triangle and the rectangle, I wrote it, but then I thought, that the length must have positive number. How to check it? Also the interpreter says, that there is some problem on the 21 line, but I do not yet understand how to fix it. Help me, please!) Thanks!

P.S. [May be It'll help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvUHS.png)

```
def simple_areas(*args):
if len(args) == 1: #The area of the circle
    args = 0.25 * 3.14 * (args[0])**2
    return ('{:.2f}'.format(args))

elif len(args) == 2: #The area of the rectangle
    args = args[0] * args[1]
    return args

elif len(args) == 3: #The area of the triangle
    if args[0] + args[1] > args[2] and args[1] + args[2] > args[0] and args[0] + args[2] > args[1]:
        args = 0.5*(args[0] * args[2])
        return args
    else:
        return 'The sum of lengths of two sides is less or equal the length of the third or is equal'
else:
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # These "asserts" using only for self-checking and not necessary for auto-   testing
    def almost_equal(checked, correct, significant_digits=2):
        precision = 0.1 ** significant_digits
        return correct - precision < checked < correct + precision

    assert almost_equal(simple_areas(3), 7.07), "Circle"
    assert almost_equal(simple_areas(2, 2), 4), "Square"
    assert almost_equal(simple_areas(2, 3), 6), "Rectangle"
    assert almost_equal(simple_areas(3, 5, 4), 6), "Triangle"
    assert almost_equal(simple_areas(1.5, 2.5, 2), 1.5), "Small triangle"

    print("Earn cool rewards by using the 'Check' button!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent in as Python has indentation as something that is required. For example, you would want

```
def f():
  print ("hi")
```

If you need something like a positive number, think about what it means for something to be positive. Should it be greater than 0, less than 0 etc.

On a final note, I would also suggest you use some variable such as area so it is clear what your function is doing. When you reuse the variable args and set it to something else, it makes it difficult to understand/read and also prone to errors. (Let's say you want to use args again later on, but you cannot since you set it to something else).

Answer (score 0):

Your error on line 21, `if name == 'main'` is because `name` doesn't exist. I think you mean `__name__`, so change that line to:

```
if __name__ == 'main':
```

If you need to check if a number is positive, then you can simply check if it is greater than 0 by using this syntax:

```
if number > 0: # Do something
```

In your case, it would be more appropriate to check if the number was not positive, so you could do this instead:

```
if not number > 0:
    print("Please enter positive numbers.")
    return # 'return' with no arguments exits the function
```

We can use the `any` function along with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to check if all of the values in `args` are positive:

```
if any(x <= 0 for x in args):
    print("Please enter positive numbers.")
    return
```

Comment: `if any(x <= 0 for x in args)` would probably be better (if e.g. the first number is _-1_, you don't have to check the other args)

Comment: Thanks for that, @SteinarLima. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Also he does indeed use `__name__`, he just stumbles when formating the code for SO (`__underscores__` before and after text makes the text __bold__)

Comment: @SteinarLima , my code is only the function, the rest of code was auto-generated

Comment: @OrangeFlash81 , "TypeError: unorderable types: float() < str()" - do I have to convery float to string?